# List not being returned from function

Tags: python, list, return

When I create a new list in my function at the end I want to return that new list to replace the values that were initially called however when the return statement runs nothing actually happens.

```
def fixNumbers(list):
    newList = []
    for i in list:
        if i > 255:
            newList.append(225)       
        elif i < 0:
            newList.append(0)
        else:
            newList.append(i)
    return newList
values1 = [-10, 100, 300]
fixNumbers(values1)
print(values1)
values2 = [127, 216, 280, 250, 50, 0, -3, 20]
fixNumbers(values2)
print(values2)
```

Comment: You need to reassign the returned value to your variable.

Comment: You are returning values.  So `values1 = fixNumbers(values1)`, etc.

Comment: @Julien I assume that I need to do that before the return statement? If so how do I go about doing that?

Comment: @Julien I'm just trying to finish an assignment for an introductory cs class and I have gotten rather confused, hence why I am asking for assistance here

Comment: You return a list but never use it. You should probably re-think your task. Do you want a new list or do you want to modify the input list *in situ*. You may also find [Getting started](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/) useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In last lines you can do like:

```
values1 = [-10, 100, 300] 
fix_numbers_1 = fixNumbers(values1)
print(fix_numbers_1)
```

Full code below:

```
def fixNumbers(list):
    newList = []
    for i in list:
        if i > 255:
            newList.append(225)       
        elif i < 0:
            newList.append(0)
        else:
            newList.append(i)
    return newList
values1 = [-10, 100, 300]
fix_numbers_1 = fixNumbers(values1)
print(fix_numbers_1)

values2 = [127, 216, 280, 250, 50, 0, -3, 20]
fix_numbers_2 = fixNumbers(values2)
print(fix_numbers_2)
```

Info:

- When you call a function and it returns something we have to store that returned value in order to use it

Comment: Great ! also please don't use builtins like list, tuple, int, str as variables, because when you override list with something, original list command will not work.